# Why It is not possible to serialize PHP built-in objects?

Tags: php, object, serialization

I have tried to unserialize a PHP Object.

**Warning: unserialize() [function.unserialize]: Node no longer exists in /var/www/app.php on line 42**

But **why** was that happen?

Even if I found a solution to unserialize simplexml objects, its good to know why php cant unserialize objects?

**To serialize simplexml object  i use this function**

```
function serializeSimpleXML(SimpleXMLElement $xmlObj) 
{

        return serialize($xmlObj->asXML());

}
```

**To unserialize an simplexml objetc i use this function**

```
function unserializeSimpleXML($str) 
{

        return simplexml_load_string(unserialize($str));

}
```

Comment: Related: [How to serialize/save a DOMElement in $_SESSION?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10398147/367456) - has an example of how to do it and even add meta information along the nodes.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

SimpleXMLElement wraps a libxml resource type. Resources cannot be serialized. On the next invocation, the resource representing the libxml Node object doesn't exist, so unserialization fails. It may be a bug that you are allowed to serialize a SimpleXMLElement at all.

Your solution is the correct one, since text/xml is the correct serialization format for anything XML. However, since it is just a string, there isn't really any reason to serialize the XML string itself.

Note that this has nothing inherently to do with "built-in" PHP classes/objects, but is an implementation detail of SimpleXML (and I think DOM in PHP 5).

Comment: There was a bug in PHP was resolved:  https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=49800  The nature of the bug was that you were allowed to serialized.

Answer (score 2):

just inherent the class(the main xml class would be best) in a other one

and use __sleep 
to store the data required to initialize simplexml(any object)

and __wake
to reinitialize the object as required

this way you can serialize(any object)

edit: remember this class needs to be accessible first,
this can be done by loading(including) the class or an __autoload

Comment: You can also use the Serializable interface.

Comment: nope, i dont see a way to use the serializable interface on a internal php object(as you connot implement 2 classes into your class)

Comment: You can extend the class that you are trying to serialize, and then implement the interface in the child, just as you are with __sleep and __wake. You can implement as many interfaces as you want.

Comment: thanks for the edu, see the note: http://nl.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#language.oop5.magic.sleep